Movesense sbem.h missing from the corelibrary
I have been working on an altered version of the offline GATT app. However, both these inclusions seem to not be present anymore in the movesense core library. They are also called within the sample app, I am attempting to develop for sensorsoftware 2.2.
#include "platform/bsp/rtc.hpp"
#include "sbem/Sbem.hpp"
My question, is there a workaround for this or are these .h files still available elsewhere (since there are release versions for the offline GATT sensor app)?
Many thanks in advance!
I have tried the following:

recloning the movensense repository
using: #include "sbem_types.h", #include "movesense_time/resources.h" and #include "sbem-code/sbem_definitions.h"

Error in building:
/movesense/samples/win_ecglogger_app/ECGIMULoggerapp.cpp:8:10: fatal error: sbem/Sbem.hpp: No such file or directory
8 | #include "sbem/Sbem.hpp"

Looks like it's a bug in the sample in the current release. It will be fixed in near future.
Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense Team

Hi PetriL, thanks for the response. I have been send the "sbem/sbem.hpp" file. However the whole sbem directory seems to be needed for this to work. Is there a timeline on the fix or a way I can have access to the directories used to build the release version of the offline_sensor_app? I'm quite over due on the timeline to start data collection in a running study.

Has been resolved with the new updated movesensecorelib
